# How to solve this infinite system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve an infinite set of coupled equations.  j is a real integer index where $-\infty<j<\infty$. {a,b,c,d,f} are variables, and K's are constants.  I need to find closed form solutions for $\{a_{j},b_{j},c_{j}\}$ in terms of only the K's. I believe the respective solutions for $\{a_{j},b_{j},c_{j}\}$ should have the same form for all j.  I don't need explicit forms for the d's or f's.

$$a_{j}+b_{j}+c_{j}=K_{j}$$

$$3a_{j}+2b_{j}+c_{j}=c_{j+1}$$

$$6a_{j}+3b_{j}+d_{j}+3f_{j}=0$$

$$3a_{j}+2b_{j}+d_{j}+2f_{j}=0$$

$$d_{j}+f_{j}-f_{j-1}=0$$

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly obtain a formal solution by treating the variables as Fourier coefficients. Multiplying every equation by $e^{ijx}$ and summing over $j$ after defining the functions

$$\{a,b,c,d,f,K\}(x)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty\{a,b,c,d,f,K\}_j e^{ijx}$$

one obtains the linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0&0\\ 
3&2 &1-e^{-ix}&0&0\\6&3&0&1&3\\3&2&0&1&2\\0&0&0&1&1-e^{ix}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a(x)\\b(x)\\c(x)\\d(x)\\f(x)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}K(x)\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

with the solution

$$\begin{pmatrix}a(x)\\ b(x)\\c(x)\\d(x)\\f(x)\end{pmatrix}=\frac{K(x)}{2(\cos x+2)}\begin{pmatrix}2(\cos x-1)\\ 3(1-e^{ix})\\ 3(1+e^{ix})\\ 6(\cos x-1)\\3(1-e^{ix})\end{pmatrix}$$

Now it isn't very hard to undo the Fourier series and obtain expressions for the unknown variables in terms of sums over the integers. As an example, let us find a formal expression for $a_j$.

First, note that

$$K(x)(\cos x -1)=\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}(K_{j+1}+K_{j-1}-2K_j)e^{ij x}$$

It remains to extract the Fourier series of $(\cos x +2)^{-1}$. A standard complex analysis argument shows that

$$(\cos x+2)^{-1}=-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}(2-\sqrt{3})^{|k|}e^{ikx}:=\sum_j {W}_j e^{ijx}$$

Multiplying the two series together we get the expression

$$a_j=\sum_{\ell=-\infty}^{\infty}K_\ell(W_{j-\ell+1}+W_{j-\ell-1}-2W_{j-\ell})=2\pi(1-1/\sqrt{3})K_j+\frac{6\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{\ell\neq j}K_{\ell}(2-\sqrt{3})^{|j-\ell|}$$

Similarly we obtain solutions for the other coefficients as well.

Comment: Thanks and wow.  I need to study this a bit, as I haven't seen this Fourier trick before.  Very cool.  But looking ahead at your result, I'm wondering about the j-L exponent.  The terms for L>>0 will get huuuge.  When I've MMa'd out numerical examples with large sets of terms rather than infinite, the variables were most strong coupled to the nearest K's, and the coupling tapered off more or less symmetrically.  Is there supposed to be a magnitude or something in there?

Comment: You are correct, there was a mistake in the calculation. Fixing parts of it as I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the $Z$ transform we have

$$
\cases{
A(z)+B(z)+C(z)=K(z)\\
3A(z)+2B(z)+C(z)-zC(z)=zc_{-\infty}\\
6A(z)+3B(z)+D(z)+3F(z)=0\\
3A(z)+2B(z)+D(z)+2F(z)=0\\
D(z)+F(z)-z^{-1}F(z)=f_{-\infty}
}
$$

and solving we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 A(z)=\frac{c_{-\infty} z (z-1)+f_{-1} z (z+1)+K(z) (z-1)^2}{z^2+4 z+1} \\
 B(z)=\frac{3 c_{-\infty} z-f_{-1} z (z+2)+3 K(z) (z-1)}{z^2+4 z+1} \\
 C(z)=\frac{z (f_{-\infty}-c_{-\infty} (z+2))+3 K(z) (z+1)}{z^2+4 z+1} \\
 D(z)=\frac{3 \left(c_{-\infty} z (z-1)+f_{-\infty} z (z+1)+K(z) (z-1)^2\right)}{z^2+4 z+1} \\
F(z) = -\frac{z (3 c_{-\infty} z+2 f_{-\infty} z+f_{-\infty}+3 K(z) (z-1))}{z^2+4 z+1}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

now knowing $K(z)$ and $c_{-\infty},f_{-\infty}$ we can calculate the inverse.

NOTE

If $K(z)$ doesn't exists in closed form then we can use the convolution theorem which states that $K(z)G(z) \leftrightarrow \{k_j\}\circledast \{g_j\}$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 a_j  + b_j  + c_j  = K_j  \\ 
 3a_j  + 2b_j  + c_j  = c_{j + 1}  \\ 
 6a_j  + 3b_j  + d_j  + 3f_j  = 0 \\ 
 3a_j  + 2b_j  + d_j  + 2f_j  = 0 \\ 
 d_j  + f_j  - f_{j - 1}  = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
we can use 3rd and 4th rows to enucleate $d$ anf $f$ as a combination of  $a$ and $b$
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 f_j  =  - 3a_j  - b_j  \\ 
 d_j  = 3a_j  \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

Thereafter we can enucleate $a$ as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 a_j  + b_j  + c_j  = K_j  \\ 
 3a_j  + 2b_j  + c_j  = c_{j + 1}  \\ 
 3a_{j - 1}  - b_j  + b_{j - 1}  = 0 \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\;\; \Rightarrow \;\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 a_j  + b_j  + c_j  = K_j  \\ 
 3a_j  + 2b_j  + c_j  = c_{j + 1}  \\ 
 3a_j  + b_j  = b_{j + 1}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\;\; \Rightarrow  \\ 
  \Rightarrow \;\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 a_j  = K_j  - b_j  - c_j  \\ 
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 3K_j  - b_j  - 2c_j  = c_{j + 1}  \\ 
 3K_j  - 2b_j  - 3c_j  = b_{j + 1}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where in the last row we have increased the index: we shall take that in due account, after solving the system, by accomodating the initial conditions.
So  we are left with
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 3K_j  - b_j  - 2c_j  = c_{j + 1}  \\ 
 3K_j  - 2b_j  - 3c_j  = b_{j + 1}  \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\;\; \Rightarrow \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b_{j + 1} }  \\   {c_{j + 1} }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  - \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   2 & 3  \\   1 & 2  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b_j }  \\   {c_j }  \\
\end{array}} \right) + 3K_j \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1  \\   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$

The matrix diagonalizes as
$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   2 & 3  \\
   1 & 2  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {\sqrt 3 }  \\
   1 & { - \sqrt 3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right)^{ - 1} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {2 + \sqrt 3 } & 0  \\
   0 & {2 - \sqrt 3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {\sqrt 3 }  \\
   1 & { - \sqrt 3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
and thus finally we get the decoupled difference equations
$$
\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {u_{j + 1} }  \\   {v_{j + 1} }  \\
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {\sqrt 3 }  \\   1 & { - \sqrt 3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {b_{j + 1} }  \\   {c_{j + 1} }  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  - \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {2 + \sqrt 3 } & 0  \\   0 & {2 - \sqrt 3 }  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {u_j }  \\   {v_j }  \\
\end{array}} \right) + 3K_j \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1  \\   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$
which can be easily solved .